# Ruby HTTP server without networking

Tags: ruby, http, networking, select, httpserver

I am trying to add an HTTP server to an existing Ruby application. The application is based around a `select` loop, and I want to handle incoming HTTP requests there too (it is important to process the requests in the same thread, or I have to jump through hoops to marshal them there).

Ruby has plenty of solutions for standalone HTTP servers, but I can't seem to find a library which implements an HTTP server on an existing socket. I don't want the HTTP library to open a port and wait, I want to feed it sockets.

The basic logic I'm looking for is this:

```
handler = SomeHTTPParsingLibrary.new
# set up handler callbacks, etc on handler...

while socket = get_incoming_connection()
    handler.handle_request(socket)
end
```

Are there any existing Ruby libraries that can work like this? HTTP is a simple enough protocol, but there are enough irritating details involved (I need cookies, basic auth, etc) that I'd rather not roll my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to roll your sleeves up a bit to figure out what methods to call, but I'd suggest trying the `HTTPParser` class from within [mongrel](https://github.com/mongrel/mongrel).

Comment: I went with WEBrick, but this turned out quite easy to accomplish by simply looking at `WEBrick::HTTPServer::run`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance through the code in `httprequest.rb` (webrick - from ruby stdlib) seems like it might suit your purpose.

A `WEBrick::HTTPRequest` object is able to accept a socket as an argument to its `parse()` method. It will then block, and return when the request object has been fully populated with the incoming HTTP request.

eg:

```
    res = HTTPResponse.new(@config)
    req = HTTPRequest.new(@config)

    # some code to "select" a socket goes here

    # sock is active, hand it over to the req object for reading.
    req.parse(sock)
    res.request_method = req.request_method
```

Of course, this assumes that this thread will block will the current request handling is complete.

OTOH, something like [**`tmm1/http_parser.rb`**](https://github.com/tmm1/http_parser.rb) might also fit your needs, but sacrifice other things (like handling cookies) in favor of speed.